# when will the python __call__ would be called?

Tags: python

I tried to understand the following code.

```
class Chain(object):

    def __init__(self, path=''):
        self._path = path

    def __getattr__(self, path):
        return Chain('%s/%s' % (self._path, path))

    def __str__(self):
        return self._path

    __repr__ = __str__

    def __call__(self, path):
        return Chain('%s/%s' % (self._path, path))


print (Chain().abc.efg("string").repos)
```

The output is:

```
/abc/efg/string/repos
```

What I don't understand is why the `__call__` method was not called in the `Chain(/abc)` , but was called in the `Chain(/abc/efg)`

Answer (score 2):

`__getattr__` is used for attribute lookup on a class instance. `__call__` is used when a class instance is used as a function.

```
Chain()                          # creates a class instance
Chain().abc                      # calls __getattr__ which returns new instance
Chain().abc.efg                  # calls __getattr__ which returns new instance
Chain().abc.efg("string")        # calls __call__
```

`__getattr__` can only handle strings that python recognizes as valid variable names. `__call__` is useful when a non-conforming string is wanted. So, for instance, `Chain().abc.def("some string with spaces")` would be a good example.

Answer (score 0):

`abc` is considered an attribute rather than a method call. Therefore it should be handled by `__getattr__` instead of `__call__`.